# How can I fix a 'context is null' error when retrieving an item and column from a SharePoint list with React and pnpjs?

Tags: reactjs, spfx, pnp-js

Retrieve one item and on column from this item to SharePoint list using React pnpjs.

I 'm starting to build an application with spfx and reac, I try to use pnpjs  for retrieve one item and on column from this item to SharePoint list using React pnpjs

but I have one error that say me the context is null

```
const WelcomeMessage = (props: IWelcomeMessageProps) =>{
   const _sp = getSP(props.context);

   console.log("context", _sp);

   const getTitleText = async () => {
      try {
         const item: any = await _sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MultilangueParam").items.getById(1)();
         console.log(item);
      } catch (error) {
         console.log("error: ", error);
      }
   }

   useEffect(() => {
     // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
      getTitleText();
   }, []);
```

I dont know why  it return that the context is null.

I need your help, thanks

Retrieve one item and on column from this item to SharePoint list using React pnpjs.**your text**

Answer (score -1):

**Quick One:**

My suggestion: I believe the missing piece in your code is this:

```js
sp.setup({
  spfxContext: context
});
```

**Detailed Answer**

This code snippet initializes the PnPjs library with the provided SharePoint context, allowing you to make API calls to the SharePoint environment.

To retrieve one item and a specific column value from a SharePoint list using React and PnPjs, you can make the following adjustments to your code:

```js
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface IWelcomeMessageProps {
  context: WebPartContext;
}

const WelcomeMessage: React.FC<IWelcomeMessageProps> = (props) => {
  const { context } = props;

  const getTitleText = async () => {
    try {
      const item = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("MultilangueParam").items.getById(1).select("Title").get();
      console.log(item.Title);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error:", error);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: context
    });

    getTitleText();
  }, []);

  return (
    // JSX code for your component
  );
};

export default WelcomeMessage;
```

Make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed, including `@pnp/sp`, and that the context prop is correctly passed to the `WelcomeMessage` component.

In the modified code, we use `sp.setup` to initialize PnPjs with the provided context. Then, we retrieve the item with ID 1 from the "MultilangueParam" list and select the "Title" column using the `select` method. Finally, we log the retrieved title value to the console.

Please ensure that you have imported the required modules (`sp` and `WebPartContext`) and that your SharePoint context is correctly passed to the component.

If you still encounter the "context is null" error, double-check that the `context` prop is being passed correctly to the `WelcomeMessage` component when it is rendered.

Let me know if you need any further assistance!